# .Net Core 3 MVC Web socket not show View page

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket

Function for Set Middle ware.

```
public static IApplicationBuilder MapWebSocketManager(this   IApplicationBuilder app,
                                                    PathString path,
                                                    WebSocketHandler handler)
    {
        return app.Map(path, (_app) => _app.UseMiddleware<WebSocketManagerMiddleware>(handler));
    }
```

Set Middle ware at StartUp.cs

```
  app.MapWebSocketManager("/ws",serviceProvider.GetService<ChatMessageHandler>());
```

It works. But i need use WS at root address http://localhost:7788. So that  i use this :

```
  app.MapWebSocketManager("",serviceProvider.GetService<ChatMessageHandler>());
```

Then my view page not show.But WS is still oky .. Any one have any suggestion about it??

Answer (score 0):

The `.Map()` function you are using is meant to execute every time you the user goes to the mentioned path. So when you do `Map("",...)`, you are overriding the default path (which will have your view page) and asking it to use your middleware instead. If you simply want to use your middleware, you can use the following in your `MapWebSocketManager`:

```
return app.UseMiddleware<WebSocketManagerMiddleware>(handler);
```

Comment: what kind of mvc project is it? razor pages or classic MVC? 
if the above code doesn't work, it must be something with your middleware. are you checking for path in your middleware?

Comment: razor pages .NET core 3.0

Comment: based on the info provided in your question, this is the way to make a middleware. if you used the above code and can't see your views but can see the views when you remove that line of code. then your issue is in your middleware and/or where you place your ` app.MapWebSocketManager` line in the code